# Is getting into grad school hard for applied mathematics?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am looking at program for grad school in applied mathematics. If I currently A 3.56 GPA, will it be a challenge to get into grad school?

Comment: Which country? What degrees do you have?

Comment: In the U.S., GPA is not so much the critical issue as letters of recommendation, and the specific courses you've taken.

Comment: I will have a bachelor of science in applied mathematics by December 2020 in a University in the U.S. I want to know for grad schools in the U.S.

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/what-should-we-do-with-the-can-i-get-into-x-program-with-3-xx-gpa/1563

Answer (score 0):

Probably no harder than anything else. You have the appropriate background. All grad admissions is competitive and there are probably more qualified applicants than slots at any given university.

I'd suggest that you cast a wide net when applying, so that your candidate places don't all have the same profile. A few really good places and one or two that you'd be happy at but not among the top few.

Like anyone, you have to make your case for success. Put together a good package with supportive letters of recommendation. The letters need to make a prediction of your success. Also, write a good Statement of Purpose for grad studies and thereafter. Talk about any research experiences, but focus the SoP on the future.

But don't worry much about a specialty within applied math. You will have plenty of time to do that as you take the required advanced courses. The first job is to pass comprehensive exams that are usually required.

And don't be put off by scary talk about 4.0 GPA or perfect GRE requirements. There are a few places where you need to consider such things, but graduate admissions isn't an accounting game. There are plenty of R1 institutions where actual humans have a good shot.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I do have good professors,and I will definitely get recommendations from them.I also do have some research experience from an REU program,and will include that in my Statement of Purpose for grad studies.